# How can I extract the weight and bias of Linear layers in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

In `model.state_dict()`, `model.parameters()` and `model.named_parameters()` weights and biases of `nn.Linear()` modules are contained separately, e.q. `fc1.weight` and `fc1.bias`. Is there a simple pythonic way to get both of them?

Expected example looks similar to this:

```py
layer = model['fc1']
print(layer.weight)
print(layer.bias)
```

Comment: "Is there a way to get a list of nn.Linear() modules in model then?" Do you wish to get the `weight` and `bias` of all linear layers in the model, or one specific one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can recover the named parameters for each linear layer in your model like so:

```
from torch import nn

for layer in model.children():
    if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
        print(layer.state_dict()['weight'])
        print(layer.state_dict()['bias'])
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the Values from a Layer.

```py
layer = model['fc1']
print(layer.weight.data[0])
print(layer.bias.data[0])
```

instead of 0 index you can use which neuron values to be extracted.

```py
>> nn.Linear(2,3).weight.data
tensor([[-0.4304,  0.4926],
        [ 0.0541,  0.2832],
        [-0.4530, -0.3752]])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the full model, no. There isn't. But you can get the `state_dict()` of that particular `Module` and then you'd have a single `dict` with the `weight` and `bias`:

```py
import torch

m = torch.nn.Linear(3, 5)  # arbitrary values
l = m.state_dict()

print(l['weight'])
print(l['bias'])
```

The equivalent in your code would be:

```py
layer = model.fc1.state_dict()
print(layer['weight'])
print(layer['bias'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of `nn.Linear()` modules in model then?

Comment: @Nourless not sure if I understood, but you can always have a `ModuleList` in a model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem when trying to prototype in pytorch and re-implementing in C++ / Eigen. I can read json...

This is what I came up with, adding a method to my model-class:

```py
  def to_obj(self):
    data = {}
    for lname,child in self.named_children():
      ldict = {}
      data[lname] = ldict
      for key,tens in child.state_dict().items():
        ldict[key] = tens.numpy().tolist()
    return data
```

Then I save using

```py
from json import dump

with open(FULLPATH,mode='w') as out:
    dump(model.to_obj(),out)
```

My case is very simple, so you might have to differentiate on child's type...